# What to use as phone ID

Tags: android, ios, iphone, uuid

I have an idea for an application that needs to get a unique phone ID so that for every phone there is a different number. What kind of unique phone IDs are available for use in apps? It would be great to use the same type of IDs for Android and Iphone.

Comment: See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: The best thing for me is Android_ID then. Any ideas how to do it on iPhone?

Comment: Apple does not allow you to track device anymore. There is no way to get a  unique phone ID on iOS. Also you should never [track device but users](http://triplesoftware.nl/2012/03/uniqueidentifier-deprecated-is-a-good-thing/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting different number for every device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424987/getting-different-number-for-every-device)

Answer (score 1):

Android:

```
android.telephony.getDeviceId()
```

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29

iPhone:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Comment: uniqueIdentifier is no longer available as of iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option on iOS is `[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString`

The only other option is some kind of user/server created identifier.